# How to refactor switch case statements in python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

This code is parts of Google app engine web apps. Any refactoring ideas of blow code?

```
def post(self):
    user = User.all().filter("id =",self.request.get('id')).get()
    for arg in self.request.arguments():
        if arg == 'name':
            user.name = self.request.get(arg)
        elif arg == 'sex':
            user.sex = self.request.get(arg)
        elif arg == 'age':
            user.age = self.request.get(arg)
        elif arg == 'interest':
            user.interest = self.request.get(arg)
        elif arg == 'location':
            user.location = self.request.get(arg)
        elif arg == 'latitude':
            user.latitude = self.request.get(arg)
        elif arg == 'longitude':
            user.longitude = self.request.get(arg)
    user.put()
    response_out_update(self, "true")
```

Answer (score 8):

```
valid_args = set(('name', 'sex', 'age', 'interest', 'location', 'latitude', 'longitude'))

for arg in self.request.arguments():
    if arg in valid_args:
        setattr(user, arg, self.request.get(arg))
```

Likely there are attributes of User objects that you don't want application users to be able to modify just by crafting an appropriate POST request. Even if this handler is restricted to admin-only with protection against CSRF, there's no obvious benefit in giving it capabilities that it doesn't need and therefore that at best will never be used, at worst someone will figure out how to abuse.